# bootstrap.min.css seems to cause a redirect

Tags: css

I have successfully applied BootStrap to 3 websites, but found an unusual bug on the third site. All 3 sites are on the same server which redirects all 404s to the index page of site 1. Now I happen to have live stats on site1 which record all visitors showing user-agent, botname, referrer, etc. I am only monitoring site 1 but every visit to site 3 appears as a redirect to site1.

The referrer is shown as https://site3.com/protect/css/bootstrap.min.css

But there are no errors on the page and they display perfectly. I have checked the code over and over and can find no exterior link, but as the page loads, I can see in the status bar that it is waiting on site3.

I have checked file permissions also, and all looks good.

But I cannot stop this ghost referral from appearing in my logs. Have you seen anything like this before?

Comment: Okay. You can try referencing the CDN.

Comment: It not because of 'css' which you tagged the question with but your server configurations. Please do tell us the server which you are using

Comment: It is on Windows Server 2008 but that can't be the problem because the 2 other sites are on the same server and the bootstrap setup is almost identical. Of 3 almost identical sites this one shows a ghost redirect even though to the visitor, nothing out of the ordinary is apparent. I checked read permissions and all 3 are identical. Even replaced the CSS files in case they were corrupt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably cannot deliver the .woff file type so glyph-fonts failed. To solve the problem, simply add the mimetype to the server for .woff and .woff2 files.

```
.woff    application/font-woff
.woff2   application/font-woff2
```

It is best to add the mimetype at server level rather than to individual sites so that unnecessary web.config files are not created (which can corrupt some site configs).

Answer (score -1):

How sure are you it's from the css file,  It's not possible to add redirection link in CSS files.

Have you try using the official Bootstrap CDN to confirm the redirection is not coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, it is the original CSS from their distribution. The CSS is logged as the "referrer" which suggests that it could not be found because the only reason for a redirect is a 404. But when viewing all pages I get no visible redirect and the pages load ok. I'll try downloading that CSS again in case it was corrupted.